# Opening macros IDE in Visual Studio without Alt + F11?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, visual-studio-express

There must be another way to do it without using the shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>   + <kbd>F11</kbd> which for me rebuilds the project for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the main Visual Studio menu **Tools - Macros - Macros IDE...**

Comment: Doesn't exist for me. Looks like they took this out in 2012 and onwards! Didn't know that. Oh well! Thanks.